# Windows service isn't writing to its log file in C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, log4net

I want to start with Windows service in C#. I would start with a simple service that would print:

```
Hello (as soon service start)
Goodbye (as soon service stop)
```

This should be pretty simple, and genuinely, in VB.net I would achieve this easily. So I've created a new *C# Windows Service* project, imported `log4net` with *nuGet package manager*.
Then I've the service class:

```
public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
{
    private static readonly log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
    public Service1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        log.Info("hello");    
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        log.Info("goodbye");
    }
}
```

and so VS creates the static class:

```
static class Program
{        
    static void Main()
    {
        ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
        ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
        { 
            new Service1() 
        };
        log.Info("NewService1");
        ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
    }
}
```

This is the `App.config` with *log4net* configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
      <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
    </configSections>
    <log4net>
      <root>
        <level value="DEBUG" />
        <appender-ref ref="FileAppender" />
        <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender" />
      </root>
      <appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
        <file value="C:\logging\operativity.log" />
        <appendToFile value="true" />
        <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%date{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff} - %level - %message%newline" />
        </layout>
      </appender>
      <appender name="ConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%date{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss} - %level - %message%newline" />
        </layout>
      </appender>
    </log4net>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

I've installed a service installer, so i've installed the service with `installutil` and started it (with success), but, alas, no hello/goodbye are logged. This style of logging is the same that I used in another project and it worked without any problems.

Why I can't get no hello this time?

Comment: Did you even check to see if the service started?

Comment: Check if the identity of the service has write access on your log file

Comment: Does the service has permission to write to that file / folder?

Comment: The service is probably running under an user account without write access to the file. ConsoleAppender will not work either, remove it. Check the windows event log for any exceptions.

Comment: Worth checking the application and system event logs if the above do not yield results.

Comment: Call `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch()` at the beginning of `Main()` and rebuild in Debug mode.  When you start the service from the Service Console, you should be prompted to enter a debug session.  My guess is an exception is occurring that's ending execution prematurely.

Comment: Note that services usually log through the event log, there are many reasons why you want to dot he same, consistently. Integration with monitoring etc. See [`ServiceBase.EventLog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.eventlog(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: How are you initialising Log4net, eg do you have something like `[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]` added to your AssemblyInfo.cs ?

Comment: There are no access issues. The problem is elsewhere.... :(

Comment: Is there anything in the Windows Event Logs that might indicate a problem?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're not hiding or removing any of the code in your example, you need to configure log4net before calling any log methods (Info, Debug, etc):

```
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
```